# RecyclerView and out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I'm using RecyclerView to display a few resource-consuming images. My implementation looks like the following:

```
private class NoteConfigItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteConfigItemAdapter.NoteConfigViewHolder> {

    public class NoteConfigViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ToggleButton tbButton;
        private final TextView tvDescription;
        private int index;

        private final View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int oldSelectedItem = selectedItem;
                selectedItem = index;
                notifyItemChanged(oldSelectedItem);
                notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
            }
        };

        public NoteConfigViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tbButton = (ToggleButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesConfig_tbButton);
            tvDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.notesConfig_tvDescription);

            tbButton.setOnClickListener(this.buttonClickListener);
        }

        public void setData(int descriptionResource, int drawableResource, int index) {

            this.index = index;
            tvDescription.setText(descriptionResource);
            Drawable background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), drawableResource, null);
            tbButton.setBackground(background);
            tbButton.setChecked(index == selectedItem);
        }
    }

    private List<NoteConfigItem> configItems;
    private int layoutResource;
    private int selectedItem = 0;

    public NoteConfigItemAdapter(List<NoteConfigItem> configItems, int layoutResource) {

        this.configItems = configItems;
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
    }

    @Override
    public NoteConfigViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);

        return new NoteConfigViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoteConfigViewHolder holder, int position) {

        NoteConfigItem item = configItems.get(position);
        holder.setData(item.stringResource, item.drawableResource, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return configItems.size();
    }
}
```

Single item's layout contains only ToggleButton and TextView:

I'm dynamically assigning background to the ToggleButton upon binding. Background is a `Drawable`, which defines two states for the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <inset android:insetTop="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetLeft="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetRight="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetBottom="@dimen/selectionBorderSize">
                    <layer-list>
                        <item>
                            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                                <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
                            </shape>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/full_range" >
                                <padding android:bottom="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:top="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:left="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:right="@dimen/selectionBorderSize" />
                            </bitmap>
                        </item>
                    </layer-list>
                </inset>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <inset android:insetTop="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetLeft="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetRight="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                    android:insetBottom="@dimen/selectionBorderSize">
                    <layer-list>
                        <item>
                            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                                <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
                            </shape>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/full_range" >
                                <padding android:bottom="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:top="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:left="@dimen/selectionBorderSize"
                                    android:right="@dimen/selectionBorderSize" />
                            </bitmap>
                        </item>
                    </layer-list>
                </inset>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`@drawable/fullRange` is a PNG image. Itself it is not so big (~hundred of such images occupy around 400kb), but it is quite big (225px x 450px), so I guess the bitmap object created from this PNG can be memory-costly.

When I run the application, I monitor the memory usage. When I only scroll through RecyclerViews, the chart looks like the following:

[image: Scrolling]

But when I start to select items, occupied memory starts to grow until OutOfMemoryException:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why arent the resources being reused/disposed?

Comment: When you work with bitmaps ensure to recycle them before to lose their reference. Bitmap are often cause of OutOfMemoryErrors

Comment: I'm using `BitmapDrawable` inside a `Drawable` defined in the XML file. How can I recycle them?

Comment: stupid question but I have to ask it, are you sure you are not just using too much memory? the baseline in the images you post is kind of high